# Computer-animated movie: downloading a dubbed copy from a foreign server: is it copyright infringement

Tags: copyright, internet, intellectual-property

I wonder if downloading a computer-animated movie dubbed for a foreign language on a foreign server is copyright infringement. I'm not sure if the dubbing process is done legally or illegally.

---

Well, I sort of know what could be the answer, I just thought I make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you making a copy of copyright material without permission of the copyright holder?

Almost certainly yes.

Is there a fair use/dealing defense, that is, among other things, is the copyright owner just as less likely to sell or rent you a copy of their film?

Almost certainly no.

Therefore it's copyright infringement.

Comment: Let's assume I travel to a country in which the computer-animated movie will not be on movie theaters, and also there is no other way to purchase it. I wonder if downloading a copy is defend-able in that case.

Comment: It's not defensible. Even if you wouldn't get to watch the movie otherwise

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks All right, now I'm more clear on that. Thanks.